# How to fix "Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type" on importdata()'s results

Tags: matlab, structure

I'm trying to import the data from a csv file. When the data is imported, a structure is created with two fields, but neither are accessible, as a dot indexing error is thrown.

These are the first few lines of one of the files

```
"U0[m/s] U0_Sd U[m/s ]  U_Sd L[N ]  D[N] Horiz. Verti. 4/3/2019 3:21 PM"
"12.933 0.056   13.919  0.914 -177.404  -262.059    0.000   0.000"
"12.977 0.050   14.038  0.972   -177.387    -262.139    0.100   0.000" 
"12.947 0.053 14.073    1.040   -177.299    -262.086    0.200   0.000"
"12.965 0.051   14.007  1.037   -177.271    -262.140    0.300   0.000"
```

The code is as follows:

```
path='directory_path';

files=dir(strcat(path,'*.csv'));

for file=files'

    cur_file=(strcat(path,file.name));
    file_struct=importdata(cur_file);
    file_data=file_struct.data;
end
```

The error I get is "Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type", but structures should be able to dot index.  Additionally, when I go to the workspace, the variable `file_struct` shows up as a cell rather than a structure, but only does so when I include the line of code initializing `file_data`.  Why is it converting the struct to a cell and how can I access my data?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share a sample of your files that produces this issue. Please see [mcve]

Comment: "U0[m/s]  U0_Sd  U[m/s ] U_Sd  L[N ] D[N]  Horiz.   Verti.  4/3/2019  3:21 PM"
"12.933 0.056 13.919 0.914 -177.404 -262.059 0.000 0.000"
"12.977 0.050 14.038 0.972 -177.387 -262.139 0.100 0.000"
"12.947 0.053 14.073 1.040 -177.299 -262.086 0.200 0.000"
"12.965 0.051 14.007 1.037 -177.271 -262.140 0.300 0.000"
These are the first few lines of one of the files being processed. Apologies if the formatting is off.

Comment: Please [edit] your original question to include it.  An MCVE means that your provided code should give that error with your sample file. So please make sure of it

Comment: “but only does so when I include the line of code initializing file_data” That makes no sense. That line does not change `file_struct`. Did you run the code in the debugger?

Comment: @Mike_Bau Please learn how to format your code so that it's legible. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `importdata` returns a `double array` and not a `struct`, so your variable named `file_struct` is not a structure at all. This is why you cannot access fields through dot notation.

Comment: @Hoki: `importdata` does return a struct, when it's presented with multi-column data with headers. See the example in Matlab's `help importdata`. It's just that OP's input data seems formatted wrong so `importdata` thinks it's a single column of string data and no headers.

Comment: BTW, that's not really a "CSV" file. CSV means "comma separated". That input stuff is space- or tab-separated, so you'd call it a "space-delimited file" or maybe a "TSV".

Answer (score 0):

If those double-quotes are really there in your input file, that's what's tripping up `importdata`. Those quotes make it think each line is a single string, instead of some space-separated values in a 2-D array. In this case, where there's only a single line of text on each line, `importdata` falls back to returning a cell array instead of that struct with `data`, `textdata`, and `colheaders` fields.

So get rid of those double-quotes!

Or use `textscan` or `readtable` instead. `readtable` is probably what you want of the two of them.